# grails 2.5 database migration plugin stuck with liquibase 2.0.5 - is it possible to hack a newer liquibase version?

Tags: grails, liquibase

Unfortunately, the [db migration plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/database-migration) is stuck with version 2.0.5 of liquibase, which has many bugs, some of which are show stoppers for us. However, liquibase 3.3. solves all of them.

We do not have the expertise needed to edit or modify the migration plugin written by Burt.

We need to use the plugin as we need to be able to auto-run the liquibase update on deployment of the war, atremote customer sites we have no access to (we just supply the war, the deploy it).

One solution might be to "hack" the 3.3. liquibase jar in. We see than in home.grails\ivy-cache\org.liquibase\liquibase-core is liquibase-core-2.0.5.jar

If we overrite this with a 3.3. jar, will ivy realise that its the wrong file, and do something like download it again?

If this is not an option, perhaps we could explode the produced war, swap out the war, and repack?

Of course, if the api which liquibase supplies has changed, this will all fail.

Any better suggestions not involving rocket science?

Our last resort is to completely abandon using the grails database migration plugin, and do everything by hand using the liquibase command line, which is very tedious.

Its very unlikely that we would be able to change to grails 3, unfortunately.

Comment: Have you considered paying Burt Beckwith to do the work?